# Node.js & ws: Easiest way to stream an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am running a node.js app. I am using ws module to send an array.

Now I want my array to stream into client, so that I can do some actions with it, while values are piping in.

I am trying to utilize **websocket-stream** module.

**Server:**

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    var stream = WebSocketStream(ws);
    var source = JSON.stringify(playlist);
    source.pipe(stream);
})
```

**Client:**

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    playlistClient = JSON.parse(event.data);
};
```

**What do I need to put in the client to receive the stream?**

Answer (score 1):

Insted of sending array, just send each element of the array as soon as they are generated in the server.

**Server**:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    playlist.forEach(function(entry){
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(entry));
    })        
})
```

**Client**

```
var playlist = [];
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    playlist.push(JSON.parse(event.data));
};
```

Comment: This is a great idea. I am now looking into implementing this.